# Program crashing when adding nodes after freeing the previous nodes

Tags: c, linked-list

Newbie question. I have this function,

```
void removeNodes(Node *start)
{
    Node *temp;
    int counter = 0;

    while(start)
    {
        temp = start;
        start = start->next;

        free(temp);
        counter++;
    }

    printf("%d node/s has been removed\n\n", counter);
}
```

In my `main()`, I have options.

1. Add node
2. Delete all nodes
3. Exit program

There was no problem in the first set of loop until I decided to free the nodes that I just created with option 2. The problem starts from here. After freeing them and I want to add another set of nodes, the program is crashing after I enter the very first node again.  First thing I did was to reset the `start` in my `main()` to `NULL`. But it's still breaking the program.

The book that I am reading don't have an explanation why this is happening. Or maybe they have it but they are on the last pages. I'm on page 340/632 =).. Newbie here. Maybe I am just missing something very simple for other veteran. Pls help me. tnx..

And by the way, This is just a sample of my `main()` function. I didn't include all.

```
    Node *start = NULL;
    int choice;
    int pos = 1;
    int data;
    int node_qty = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("1. Add node\n2. Delete all nodes\n3. Quit    ");
        scanf(" %d", &choice);

        if(choice == 1)
        {
            if(!node_qty)
            {
               printf("Enter the value of the first node: ");
               scanf(" %d", &data);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Enter a value: ");
                scanf(" %d", &data);

                do
                {
                    printf("Enter the position: ");
                    scanf(" %d", &pos);

                    if(pos > node_qty + 1)
                    {
                        printf("Invalid input. Current node quantity: %d\n", node_qty);
                        printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
                        system("PAUSE");
                        system("cls");
                    }
                }while(pos < 1 || pos > node_qty + 1);
            }

            insertNode(&start, pos, data);

            printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
            system("PAUSE");
            system("cls");

            node_qty++;
        }
        else if(choice == 2)
        {
            removeNodes(start);

            //reset
            start = NULL;
            node_qty = 0;

            printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
            system("PAUSE");
            system("cls");
        }
        else if(choice == 3)
        {
            printf("Program ends");
            break;
        }
    }

    //then after all of that, I am making sure that it will free the nodes
    removeNodes(start); //I don't think the problem is here.
```

This is my add node function

```
void insertNode(Node **start, int pos, int data)
{
    Node *temp1 = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp1->data = data;

    Node *temp2 = *start;

    if(pos == 1)
    {
        temp1->next = *start;
        *start = temp1;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < pos - 2; i++)
        {
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }

        temp1->next = temp2->next;
        temp2->next = temp1;
    }
}

//and for checking, here's my print function
void printNode(Node *start)
{
    while(start)
    {
        printf("%d ", start->data);

        start = start->next;
    }

    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Comment: You need to post the rest of the code. I suspect you have some issue populating the list.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is elsewhere, and it's not a properly formed linked list. Or maybe it's something else. Perhaps you should show the code that processes the options?

Comment: You should post a complete minimal   and verifiable example.

Comment: Ok. I will.. w8.. i'll just edit it.

Comment: `insertNode()` loops `pos-2` times, doing `temp2 = temp2->next`.   This gives undefined behaviour if `temp2` is ever NULL, and the code is not checking for that.   This is particularly relevant since, effectively, the code after the loop inserts `temp2->next` into the list without further checks.   If any error is made here, the loop in `removeNodes()` - which keeps going until it finds a NULL - will also have undefined behaviour.

Comment: -> next is never set to NULL. So how can you detect the end of the list?

Comment: Since you are using `pos` without inserting the first node, you need to reset `pos` if you use the list again.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing `start` when it is `NULL` if you create a new node right after deleting all nodes in your program.
You should find a way to prevent the usage of the `->` operator on `start` when it is `NULL` in `insertNode()`.

You could add

```
if(*start == NULL)
{
    *start = temp1;
    return;
}
```

right after creating `temp1` which is the new node.
Only the first position is available for insertion when the list is empty so the value of `pos` is irrelevant.

Another thing is as [PeterJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6110094/peterj) pointed out, the `next` of the new node you add at the end of the list is not made `NULL` in `insertNode()` function.
Without this, you can't tell when you reach the end while traversing the list with your `printNode()` function.

So add a `temp1->next = NULL;` right after creating `temp` in `insertNode()`.